# Spring boot Auto Configuration trying to load beans from dependent project

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Spring Boot is loading Beans from external dependent jars .

How can we stop Autoconfigration of loading Bean from dependent jar .
Below is the annotation used .

```
@Configuration
@SpringBootApplication(excludeName = {"com.test.core"})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.test.myhazelcast"})
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class BelHazelcastApplication { ...
```

I want Spring boot not to configure any bean com.test.core.* which is a dependent module .

But Take beans that are presenst in com.test.myhazelcast.* package .

Comment: Do you have any other @Configuration classes in com.test.myhazelcast?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `excludeName` attribute of `SpringBootApplication` is used to exclude an autoconfiguration class by its name, not to exclude a package from component scanning.

Because you `SpringBootApplication` with the default for the packages to component scan, it will component scan from whatever package BelHazelcastApplication is in.

If this package is "com.test" then that will include components in "com.test.core".

I'd remove this line:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.test.myhazelcast"})
```

and change this:

```
@SpringBootApplication(excludeName = {"com.test.core"})
```

to be:

```
@SpringBootApplication(basePackages = {"com.test.myhazelcast"})
```